# How do I clone/merge a Linux Mint partition to a Windows installed SSD and still keep dual boot?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, partition, windows, dual-boot

So I have Linux Mint installed in a SSD and Windows 10 installed in another SSD, got dual boot running perfectly, but now I need to give away one of my SSD, so I need to merge everything to a single SSD and still keep dual boot working fine, I already got 334,39GB of unallocated space in the destination SSD, I also know how to resize partitions to make them fit, using livecd and stuff, but my biggest concern is about dual boot.

How do I do this task and still keep dual boot working?

[image: Source SSD]

[image: Destination SSD]

Comment: Easiest really is a new install, using Something Else & restore from your backup. Good way to test that backup has everything you must have, while you still have old SSD. Any other method, requires copy & lots of edits of UUIDs, GUIDs, fstab and maybe other settings. And total reinstall of grub. You cannot use dd with gpt. You may be able to use some of the other tools, but they may not update UUIDs, etc. And they all will require reinstall of grub. Make sure Windows UEFI boot files are in ESP on Windows drive.

Answer (score 0):

I simply decided to copy and paste every partition in gparted, and then I tried to boot it, for some reason everything worked like I didn't change anything, I have no idea how this worked, but it did.